# Platformer Double-Jump and Dash Not Working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Working on a platformer where as the player moves over an energy orb, they can choose to fuel either a double jump or a dash. No errors according to unity, but when I press the corresponding keys for my double jump and dash, neither work. Simply nothing happens. Oh and btw my character randomly freezes and I have to tap the movement key again to get him to continue moving this is also a new issue so may be related. I am very new to all this.

```
public class playerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float speed;
    [SerializeField] int dashEnergy = 1;
    [SerializeField] int doubleJumpEnergy = 1;
    private Rigidbody2D body;
    private Animator anim;
    private int jumpCount;

        private void Awake()
        {
            body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        }
    
        private void Update()
        {

        //Left-Right Movement
        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && jumpCount == 0)
        {
            jump();
            jumpCount += 1;
        }
        body.velocity = new Vector2(horizontalInput*speed, body.velocity.y);

    //Character Turns Towards Movement Direction
    if (horizontalInput > 0.01f)
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(-5, 5, 5);
        if (horizontalInput < -0.01f)
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(5,5,5);

           //Dash & doubleJump
           void doubleJump()
           {
             if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)&&jumpCount==1 && doubleJumpEnergy==1)
             {
               jump();
               doubleJumpEnergy -= 1;
             }
           }
          void Dash()
           {
             if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) && dashEnergy == 1)
             {
               body.velocity = new Vector2(horizontalInput*speed*60, body.velocity.y);
               dashEnergy -=1;
             }
           }
    }
    public void jump()
    {
        body.velocity = new Vector2(body.velocity.x, speed);
    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.tag == "EnergyBubble" && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.V))
        {
          dashEnergy += 1;
        }
        if(collision.gameObject.tag == "EnergyBubble" && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.C))
        {
          doubleJumpEnergy += 1;
        }
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
        {
          jumpCount=0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm honestly surprised this compiles because you've got `void doubleJump()` and `void Dash()` just right there in the middle of your Update loop. Once you get that fixed the problem you're having is that you're trying to set the velocity at each action. This means the last action checked will always win.

Comment: @Chuck: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar huh TIL thanks. But I don't think they're getting called even anyways, right? On my phone so maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Nah, they're not getting called at all. I doubt they even exist in the compiled code - it seems like something the compiler would optimise out. Edit: Looking at SharpLab, it seems like the compiler does leave the local methods even if they're unused. Weird.

Comment: @Chuck how would I set it up without restating the velocity?

Comment: Try Input.GetKeyUp instead of Input.GetKey in your input condition to call jump function

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, all physics operations should be used from fixedUpdate method, for example:

```
void FixedUpdate() 
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Space"))
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, 10);
}
```

It's needs for smoothly physics movement.

Or call your own method from it:

```
void FixedUpdate() 
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Space"))
        jump();
}
```

Then you have a bug in condition check statements, you have to use:

```
//Dash & doubleJump
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && jumpCount == 1 && doubleJumpEnergy >= 1)
    {
        body.velocity = new Vector2(0, 2);
        doubleJumpEnergy -= 1;
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) && dashEnergy >= 1)
    {
        body.velocity = new Vector2(horizontalInput * speed * 60, body.velocity.y);
        dashEnergy -= 1;
    }
```

Problem with a condition check statements, you need to have ">=" operator: `dashEnergy >= 1` and `doubleJumpEnergy >= 1` instead `==`